# Asp.net MVC How To Open New Window From Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, popup, actionresult

So I have a scenario where I want to return my ActionResult...Return View("ViewName", "MasterPageName",model); in a popup window of a specific size I can pass...

E.G.:

```
public ActionResult PopUp()
{
  //do some work...

  //I want this returned in a popup window/modal dialog of some sort...
  return View("ViewName","MasterPageName",model); 
}
```

what is a reasonable way to accomplish this from the controller in asp.net mvc?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can be done on server side but you can decorate your action links like

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Pop Up", "PopUp", null, new {target="_blank"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the client side browser from a Controller on the server-side.  What you can do is output script in your returned view, or call a controller that returns data via an AJAX call and pop-up from the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can really do from your controller as this is code that executes on the server as the result of a http request and returns a response of some form or other. You will need to do this on the client, probably using javascript or alternatively you can call your controller action and specify the [target attribute of the a tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as '_blank'.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try dynamically loading the rendered view using `jQuery.load()`